I can't create bevel
I'm using Blender 4.1 on Windows 10, here is my problem :
I want to bevel this part on the 2 sides that are quite long. I tried different options like create a bevel in edit mode but I have either this result or nothing that happen. I tried with a bevel modifier and as limit method vertex group with the group containing only one edge but nothing happen.
If you need more details do not hesitate ask.
Thank you in advance for your answers

Hello, I'm not sure how you could create a bevel here, the topology doesn't allow to create any correct bevel, maybe you need to find another way to do what you want? Maybe tell a bit more?

@moonboots I want to create a surface like a topological map extrude it to have some thikness and bevel 2 of the 4 edges with a specific bevel. I just tried again a manage to get a bevel but there is a lot of vertices that are not linked well to the model

So you want to keep your dense topology and simultaniously bevel the edge?

Well, if you really want to keep every single vert you have in this mesh, the only way to do such a bevel would be by doing it procedurally in the shader editor not physically. But with such a big bevel this could present a not completely pleasing result.
Since you want/need the dense mesh, I found a compromise which you may like.

Look how big you want the bevel to be and remember the amount of edges and
vertices that are overlapping ( The edges within the blue area in the picture)

Select these edges with alt+LMB in a way like mine, but keep the corneres!!

Press ctrl+x to dissolve the selected edges. It should look like this afterwards.

Select the corner edges and bevel them, I get a result like this. Maybe that's what you're looking for.


In general bevel need space, with edges and vertices close by, you always get a result like you got, if you're going over the clamp overlap value. Unless you're willed to use the materials to simulate bevels, you always have to clear up the space for them to work properly.
I Hope it helped

That is what I was looking Thank you

The Bevel modifier is meant to work within a single segment on the adjacent cells (there is an option to remove 'clamp overlap' but it can lead to strange results).

So, unless you want to strongly decimate your geometry, it's easier to use a workaround, such as a boolean modifier.


I had this idea but the problem is that it won't follow the shape of my design, it's quite irregular and i don't want something like this, I want the same cut but it needs to follow the corner
